# Getting 500 error page on logout by Selenium Webdriver script

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Updated with code

```html
driver.get("https://stage.ab.org/");

System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
System.out.println(driver.getPageSource());

driver.findElement(By.id("txt-username")).sendKeys("Username");
driver.findElement(By.id("pwd-password")).sendKeys("Passw0rd");
driver.findElement(By.id("login-widget-submit")).click();

Thread.sleep(2000);

driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".username-link-container")).click();

Thread.sleep(8000);
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 9);  
WebElement link = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("alinkSignOut")));
link.click();
```

I do not get any errors in Eclipse.

When the Webdriver script runs (logging out a user) it gives 500 Error page.  When I do it manually, I am able to it successfully.  What is going on with Selenium?

Comment: You forgot to ask a question

Comment: Updated with a question! :)

Comment: unfortunately it is not a very precise one. You have forgot to post your code. You have forgot to tell us what you have tried to solve your own problem. You have pretty much gone to a mechanic shop and asked what is wrong with your car, without bringing your car for them to look at.

Comment: Updated again with code.  I do not get any error in Eclipse.  All I see is tge 500 error page on the browser.  I do not get this error with manual sign out

Comment: 500 is a server error. While it's possible Selenium is triggering things in such a way as to cause it, it is the server's responsibility - but we are powerless to help you without knowing what the error is (a full stacktrace if possible). Your code doesn't help with that.

Answer (score 0):

Some issues with VPN, working fine now